# NUC5i3RYH and Kingston 120 GB SATA Industrial Solid State Drive

Tags: boot, ssd, intel-nuc

I just received my shiny new NUC and M.2 SSD, Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse and BenQ GL2250 monitor.

I fired it all up and installed Ubuntu 14.4 from a USB drive. Everything worked flawlessly. I removed the USB stick and booted from the SSD, perfect. I started installing my applications and suddenly strange things started to happen. The Launcher disappeared and the visual output was not what I expected. Eventually the whole system hung. I tried to reboot and nothing happened - blue screen.

I thought there may be some driver issue and decided to try Ubuntu 15.10, just in case there was some updated driver there that would solve my problem. I was able to boot from the 15.10 stick and started the Ubuntu installation. When it got to the stage of formatting the drives, no drives appeared in the menu. I had no choice but to exit the installation process. Now I am not able to boot from the USB or the SSD, even to run Ubuntu from the USB (`Panic not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount Root FS on unknown block(1,0)`).

Now when I look in Intel's VisualBios, under `Devices > SATA`, it shows `Sata Port [not installed]` and `M.2 Sata [not installed]`. I tried re-seating the SSD just in case, but to no effect.

It looks like something has gone wrong with my hardware(?), but is it the SSD that's broken or the NUC itself? Could Ubuntu have broken something?

I have no idea how to recover from this or where to start looking. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: The NUC shouldn't be an issue. I do have the exact same setup, but with a Samsung EVO M.2 instead and it works perfectly. I'm sure you won't have any problem once they send you the new disk.

Answer (score 0):

Response from Kingston tech support:

"From the description you provided, it appears as though your product SM2280S3/120GBK has developed a fault and we recommend that you replace it through your point of purchase."